# Find all duplicate lines and display non matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an easy way to do this in javascript?

```
arr = ["red","blue","green","red","blue", "yellow"]

output = ["green", "yellow"]
```

Basically if a value is shown only once in an array output it. The order is random.

There are easy ways to do this in php, javascript is confusing me.

Need to run this on at least 4000 values, not sure what's faster, regex or array functions?

Thanks for any help.

code having problem with: myarrs values aren't accessible outside the function, I am stuck there. The file loads otherwise,

```html
var txt = '';
var myarr = '';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 0 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
   txt = xmlhttp.responseText;  
   myarr = txt.split("\n");
});

//alert(myarr.length);
      
xmlhttp.open("GET","list.csv",true);
xmlhttp.send();

var map = new Object();
for(var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++)
{
    if(map[myarr[i]] === undefined)
    {map[myarr[i]] = 1; }
    else
    {map[myarr[i]]++; }
}
var result = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++)
{   
    if(map[myarr[i]] > 1)
    { //do nothing
 }
    else
    {result.push(myarr[i]);}
}

console.debug(result);
document.write(result);
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please post your code so far, and a demo to reproduce your particular issue.

Comment: a type-safe variant: ["red","blue","green","red","blue", "yellow"].filter(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)===c.lastIndexOf(a);})

Answer (score 0):

If order of the unique elements doesn't matter, you can store the item in an object and increment the count, like this

```
var arr = ["red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "yellow"], obj = {};
arr.forEach(function(currentItem) {
    obj[currentItem] = (obj[currentItem] || 0) + 1;
});
```

And then filter out all the items for which the value is not 1, to get the unique values

```
var unique = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(currentItem) {
    return obj[currentItem] === 1;
});

console.log(unique);
# [ 'green', 'yellow' ]
```

**Note:** If you don't declare the variables with `var` keyword, they will become global properties.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var txt = '';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  //for local files use status zero not 200
  if(xmlhttp.status == 0 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
   myarr = txt.split("\n");
  display = myarr.filter(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)===c.lastIndexOf(a);});
   document.write(display);
   // myarr.replace(",", "<br>");
   }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","list.csv",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The only thing I don't understand is why does the page keep trying to load after it finishes processing the whole file.